# How to close and just later add HTML element in D3.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Now I have the next code:

```
d3.select("#commiterStatsContainer")
        .append("div").attr("class", "chip")
        .append("img").attr("src", committers[i].avatar)
        .text(committers[i].login);
```

but it adds my text inside of the `<img>...</img>` tag. How can I close `<img>` and just later to add my text?

Answer (score 2):

The append method returns a new selection containing the appended elements ([See documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append)). So following your code:

```
d3.select("#commiterStatsContainer") // initial selection
  .append("div").attr("class", "chip") // new selection with a div
  .append("img").attr("src", committers[i].avatar) // new selection of img in that div
  .text(committers[i].login); // text for the img tag in the div.
```

Instead, try:

```
var div = d3.select("#commiterStatsContainer")
  .append("div").attr("...");

div.append("img").attr("....");
div.append("p").html("....");
```

The variable `div` is a selection of the newly created div, you then can use `div.append()` to append new elements to that div.